# use functtion in Controller extend

Tags: laravel

Controller **1**:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
class HomeController extends Controller
```

Controller **2**:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Games;
class ExchangeController extends Controller
```

i have problem when using function in controller, in 1st controller on same level as Controller is extended then $this->rollback method works, but with 2nd controller i cant access it but still can access If I rename the function, why can't I call the function named rollback in case 2 but can use in case 1

Comment: Since you are not in the same namespace as `Controller`, you need to import it : `use App\Htpp\Controllers\Controler`

Comment: App\Http\Controllers\Controller in the 2nd case it is certain because otherwise it will say notfound so still giving the same problem

Comment: you need to use App\Http\Controllers;  after namespacein the 2-nd Controller

Comment: i am using App\Http\Controllers\Controller in 2nd case , it executes functions in Controller but except function named rollback, App\Http\Controllers gives me a notfound error